How do i set sql connection when creating a Logic App in Azure?
I have created a Logic App in Azure. I go to the Logic App Designer option in the menu and click on "http". It brings up a screen and under Parameters tab I have a URI.
Now if i run that URI in Postman it gives an error Login failed for user 'useradmin'.
Where is the connection string option for the Logic app set and how can i change it ?

Sorry but show us some screenshots.

To connect to sql server you can use below design:

Then type sql in next action and then select any action below SQL Server connector:

After selecting now you will be able to get below action and in below action type all details and it connection gets established:

To run this logic app design, you can use url from first step (post url).
